# Can i view all my files the way the computer reads them?

Tags: file, binary

We know the computer understands only binary i.e. 0 and 1, so technically all files at the lowest level are nothing but comprised entirely of 0's and 1's. How do i view the binary file of any regular file ? (Correct me if i'm wrong, im in my 1st year of CS )

Comment: There is no practical reason to see the data as 0s and 1sm mainly because from programmer's point of view you're operating at least on single bytes, which consist of 8 bits, or processor words, which (nowadays, for modern PCs) consist of 4 and 8 bytes respectively for x86 (32bit) and x64 (64bit) processors.

Answer (score 2):

Correction: Computers can be said to *store* things as binary, or sometimes as base 256.  However, what they *understand* are values.  Values are numbers, ideas, concepts.  To communicate them however, we need a representation.  For example: How many apples I have on the desk is a value.  I can *represent* that value in decimal (20 apples) or in binary (0b10100 apples) or in hexadecimal (0x14 apples), or even base64 (U apples), but no matter the representation, the number of apples is unchanged.

Similarly, the most common way to think of stored files is as a series of 8 bit bytes. Therefore the most common way to think of stored files is not base two, but base 256!  However, that's too many symbols for most people, so most people analyze files in base 16: hexadecimal.  The same values, just a different representation.

There are many programs available which can open a file and show you the hexadecimal content, or if you're a programmer, it's pretty easy to make your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view what the 1's and 0's are, you can open the file with a Hex Editor. This should list each byte for you. From there you will have to look at each byte (usually in hex, like FF, or 0xFF) and decode it to the 1's and 0's from there.